# changing from day-month-year to day/month/year in execl

Tags: excel, date

hi i have big table with unorganize date they made to formals

```
1- like this 20-12-2013
2- like this 20/12/2013
```

what i need to organize all the date to NO# form to use it in Sql

thanks for you help

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of your current data and the desired result ?

Answer (score 0):

Hilight the cells you wish to convert and run this small macro:

```
Sub DateFixer()
    For Each r In Selection
        With r
            ary = Split(Trim(.Text), "-")
            .Clear
            .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            .Value = DateSerial(ary(2), ary(1), ary(0))
        End With
    Next r
End Sub
```